# MYSQL SELECT row when row data is lesser than previous

Tags: mysql, sql

I am have a log table with column (id,user,flag)
The table data will be like

```
id   | user  | flag
----------------------
1    | Tom   | 1  
2    | Joy   | 1  
3    | Tom   | 2  
4    | Tom   | 3  
5    | Tom   | 2  
6    | Joy   | 3  
7    | Tom   | 4  
8    | Joy   | 1
```

The question is if the user is having increasing values in flag row by row ignore it (that is correct flow) and from any point the flog value is lesser than the previous values select it also in that if the flag had value 4 in that user ignore him

In the table data the user tom has flag (1,2,3,**2**,4) i need to ignore it because the user having value 4 and in the case of joy (1,3,**1**) I have to select this one because the flag is having 1 after 3

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I dont understand clearly. Can you add expected output to clarify?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you only want to know if the most recent value for flag is the maximum value for that user?

Comment: for all users the flag value is continues i have to find if the flow got broken by finding small  value is coming after large  values like (1,2,3,1) if so i have to select it and value 4 is the final flag if its there leave the user even the flow was broken

Comment: Not a job for SQL. It can be achieved with a stored procedure, though.

Comment: So, you want to SELECT all rows where the latest value for that user is not the max value for that user?

Comment: @Axiac Are you kidding?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if I fully understood your requirement, esspecially which flag should be ignored or not
I belive you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
WHERE flag < (
   SELECT flag
   FROM table1 t2
   WHERE t2.user = t1.user
     AND t2.id < t1.id
   ORDER BY id desc
   LIMIT 1
)
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecdd18/5

```
| id | user | flag |
|----|------|------|
|  5 |  Tom |    2 |
|  8 |  Joy |    1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

A way of comparing values from one row with the ones of a previous one is to use user-defined variables like `where @flag < flag`. The solution would be rather easy. In your case, however, one has additionally to consider only values of the same user. This makes the query a litte more complicated, but here you go:

```sql
set @user='', @flag:= 0;
select final.id, final.user, final.flag
from (select *, @user := user as userTemp, @flag := flag as flagTemp
from (select * from sometable order by user) oByUser
where
  (@user = user and @flag < flag) OR
  (@user <> user)) final
order by id
```

I used the following schema derived from your demo data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sometable (`id` int, `user` varchar(3), `flag` int);
INSERT INTO sometable (`id`, `user`, `flag`) VALUES
    (1, 'Tom', 1),
    (2, 'Joy', 1),
    (3, 'Tom', 2),
    (4, 'Tom', 3),
    (5, 'Tom', 2),
    (6, 'Joy', 3),
    (7, 'Tom', 4),
    (8, 'Joy', 1);
```

Then, applying the query yields the following result:

```sql
id|user|flag
1 |Tom |1
2 |Joy |1
3 |Tom |2
4 |Tom |3
6 |Joy |3
7 |Tom |4
```